# Do I need a surrogate key in a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, database-design

```
create table A (
    id int(10) not null, 
    val1 varchar(255), 
    primary key (id)
);
```

Approach [a]:

```
create table B (
    a_id int(10) not null, 
    val2 varchar(255), 

    foreign key (a_id) references A(id)
);
```

Approach [b]:

```
create table B (
    id int(10) not null, 
    a_id int(10) not null, 
    val2 varchar(255), 

    foreign key (a_id) references A(id), 
    primary key (id)
);
```

By choosing [a], I can avoid creation of the "id" surrogate key in table 'B'. Which is the preferred approach for creating table 'B' from a modeling perspective?

Comment: I am trying to model a one-to-many relationship here. But even with option [a] contrary to your statement, I am able to create multiple rows in 'B' for an entry in 'A'. Hence the confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand it : in [a], you are creating a 1:1 relationship, in [b] you are not.
**They aren't alternatives!**

In case [b], if table A would hold invoices, table B could be used for invoicelines whereas in [a] this cannot, since there can only be one record for each record in table A. (Thus only 1 invoiceline per invoice)

So, if you really want an answer, use [b], your [a] construct could be replaced with one table only, and is probably not what you mean. (also since you didn't set a primary key, the same as the FK in a 1:1 relationship)

Comment: This seems not to be true, as a_id is neither declared primary nor unique. Both solutions do the same. [b] allows for unique identification of a record in table B using its id. In [a] one cannot uniquely identify and therefore manipulate a single record, apart from using val2 too, which does not have to be unique either.

Comment: @malach, thanks for the tip. Guess I overlooked the fact that i will not be able to modify a single record in table 'B' without a unique primary key.

Answer (score 4):

You never *need* a surrogate key (hence it's name). It looks like you're mixing a logical model and a physical model. For your logical model, you presumably would have

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    Val1 varchar() not null,
    constraint PK_A KEY (Val1) --?
)

CREATE TABLE B (
    Val1 varchar() not null,
    Val2 varchar() not null,
    constraint PK_B KEY (Val2), --? or Val1,Val2?
    constraint FK_A FOREIGN KEY (Val1) references A
)
```

(The above in made-up SQL, but hopefully you see the point)

Now, for a physical model, you might introduce surrogates wherever they make sense - where the logical keys are long (e.g. varchars). But whether you do or not is really up to you. And remember to enforce the logical keys still

Comment: +1 for mentioning surrogate keys and phsyical model. The logical design should never use surrogate keys.

Answer (score 1):

For surrogate keys in general,

A professor in my Computer Science course says "No".

Practical experience for me, says, yes.

I rather use one despite the increase space just for the sake of easy to read SQL statements, and more flexibility in case of requirement changes.

Comment: That's not the question here. But as far as the case against Surrogate keys go it has nothing to do with increased space. (not that I am against them perse)

Comment: Well, space's not the big concern here for the associate professor who said 'no' when I suggest a surrogate key to a design, it's more of correctness of design, which I think it's the main issue of contention.